# CPU temp - Dell vs Intel

Tags: dell, central-processing-unit, intel

I'm troubleshooting a DELL PowerEdge M630 (VRTX).  I see CPU temp reaching at least as high as 74C.  Dell says it is good until 85C.  I looked up the CPU specs on Intel's site, and they say 74C is the max operating temp.  I told DELL that, but they insist that their fresh air configuration makes it good until 85C.

Who do I believe?

Answer (score 1):

No matter how "fresh" the air is, the temperature is the temperature. I would use the value from the chip manufacturer, which clearly states that the maximum allowable value for heat spreader temperature is 74C.

Comment: From a physical point of view, I fully agree and think this statement by Dell is really strange. On the other hand: Dell is the vendor/OPs contract partner and if they specify 85˚C and provide warranty for this value, it's their problem (and you really have nothing in hand against them in this case anyway).  I would want to get this in writing though, together with the statement that the warranty fully covers this temperatur range.

Answer (score 0):

Fresh Air Configuration of VRTX allows CPU up to 85C. So there should not be any issue. If temperature reaches beyond that, thermal control will kick in and throttle CPU.